# Automorphism of $\mathbb{R}(t)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{R}(t)$ be the rational functions in variable $t$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$.

I am asked to find that the function $\varphi: GL(2,\mathbb{R})\to Aut(\mathbb{R}(t)/\mathbb{R})$ given by $\varphi(g)=\sigma_g$, where $\sigma_g(t)=\frac{at+b}{ct+d}$ where $ad-bc\ne 0$.
I am asked to find its kernel and prove it's surjective.

For kernel I found that: $\varphi(g)(t)=\frac{at+b}{ct+d}=t$, so we should have a real solution to $at+b=ct^2+dt$, which means that we should have: $(d-a)^2+4bc\ge 0$ and $ad-bc\ne 0$, is there any other characterization for this kernel?

As for surjectiveness, I need to show that every $\sigma_g \in Aut(\mathbb{R}(t)/\mathbb{R})$ there exists a $g\in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that: $\varphi(g)=\sigma_g$.
Doesn't this follow because the only automorphism of $\mathbb{R}(t)$ is a Mobius transformation?

Comment: $\frac{at+b}{ct+d}=t$ gives that $at+b=ct^2+dt$ ie.  $b=c=0$ and $a=d$.

Comment: @reuns ok thanks. How about the surjectiveness?

Comment: An automorphism leaving $\Bbb{R}$ fixed is determined by where it sends $t$ (interesting as well to prove that all the automorphisms must leave $\Bbb{R}$ fixed)